# Converting an array of dates to datetime format and comparing them

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to convert an array of dates and times string to an array of `datetime` object so I can compare the dates and find the newest one (the one most in the future).

First I convert and then combine the dates and time. 
I'm struggling to create an array of `datetimes` and after some research I'm not sure if it is possible.

```
dates = ['2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-19','2019-02-19']
times = ['06:15', '18:30', '19:45', '14:20', '16:10','06:10', '18:35', '19:40', '14:25', '16:15' ]
dates_count = len(dates)  
dates_obj = []
times_obj = []

for i in range(dates_count):
    dates_obj.append(datetime.strptime(dates[i], '%Y-%m-%d'))  
    times_obj.appned(datetime.strptime(times[i], '%H:%M'))
    dates_times_obj = datetime.combine(datetime.date(dates_obj[i]), datetime.time(times[i]))
    print (dates_times_obj)
```

Output error

```
 dates_times_obj = datetime.combine(datetime.date(dates_obj[i]), datetime.time(times[i]))                                                              
    TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the builtin function max as follow:

```
newest_date = max(
   datetime.datetime.strptime( d + " " + t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" ) 
   for d, t in zip( dates, times )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime(dates_obj[i] + times[i], '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M').date()
```

So in your code it will the following:

```py
dates_times_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates_obj[i] + times[i], '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a typo, since you referred to `times[i]` instead of `times_obj[i]`. Additionally, if you don't need the lists of dates and times object, I would suggest to make the use of some nice features of python language, like `zip`:

```
dates = ['2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-18','2019-02-19','2019-02-19']
times = ['06:15', '18:30', '19:45', '14:20', '16:10','06:10', '18:35', '19:40', '14:25', '16:15' ]

for date_str, time_str in zip(dates, times):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M').time()
    dates_times_obj = datetime.combine(date_obj, time_obj)
    print(dates_times_obj)
```